# Solving the nth number of this recurrence and cleaning it up using the binomial theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binomial-theorem

Given this recurrence: a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> – a<sub>n-2</sub>

I was told to create a function that would solve for a<sub>n</sub>.

I thus came up with $a_n=\frac{\alpha^{n}-\beta^{n}}{i\sqrt{3}}$

Where $\alpha=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

The professor then asked the following

Your expression for $a_n$ most likely contains the imaginary number
i. Use the binomial theorem to obtained a nicer expression for $a_n$.

How do I go about doing that? Thank you.

Comment: Your formula does *not* solve for $a_n$. It is only one specific solution, namely the one where $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$. There are infinitely many other sequences fitting the recursion and your formula $(\alpha^n-\beta^n)/(i\sqrt{3})$ does not describe any of them. So you did not really "solve for $a_n$" in a general sense. The most general solution would contain $i$, or at least $\sqrt{-3}$.  If all you want is one specific solution, just take $a_n = 0$ for all $n$. That works. :)

Comment: My solution does have i in it though! Am I missing something?

Comment: I just meant that for a *general* two-term linear recursion $a_n = c_1a_{n-1} + c_2a_{n-2}$ it is pointless to insist on formulas for the terms that avoid expressions going beyond the context of the original sequence (e.g., the sequence may be all integers but it's absurd to require no irrational numbers anywhere at all in the formula).  Your setting is very special because every solution is *periodic*. Starting with $a_0$ and $a_1$,  you'll always have $a_6 = a_0$ and $a_7 = a_1$, so the sequence repeats with period 6 (or period a factor of 6).

Comment: Ohhh. I understand what you mean now. I forgot to mention that this recursion problem was asked upon the basis that $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$. I apologize that I totally forgot to mention that in my original question. I appreciate your input and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\alpha = e^{i\pi/3}$ and $\beta=e^{-i\pi/3}$. We then have
$$\alpha^n - \beta^n = e^{in\pi/3}-e^{-in\pi/3} = 2i\sin(n\pi/3)$$
This gives us
$$a_n = \dfrac{\alpha^n - \beta^n}{i\sqrt3} = \dfrac2{\sqrt3}\sin\left(n\pi/3\right)$$